# How to create a drop down menu like displayed on Amazon?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

I am kind of new to web development. I am trying to create a drop down menu. which is something like:

```
<select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

but this is not exactly what I want. I want to create a drop down list very similar to the one on Amazon.com (the dropdown list beside "Search"), shown in following pic. so whenever user click on the button, list will be displayed in the button as text.

Answer (score 1):

To start, check out http://www.codecademy.com for its brief introductions to `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`, and (more to your point here) jQuery.  You can create this effect with very little effort after getting a cursory understanding of `jQuery` and `CSS`.

http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to show the drop downs when user click on the button then it is better to do it in jquery.Please do like bellow

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$("#downarrow").click(function(){
$("#dropdown").show();
})
</script>

<div id="downarrow"></div>
<div id="dropdown" style="display:none;">
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>
```